# How to add a new column to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add new column in a dataframe, depends on if-else condition
this is my code but there is an error

```
#Power variables
ExcellentPower = -80
GoodPower = -90
MediumPower = -100
 # Quality Variables
ExcellentQuality = -10
GoodQuality = -15
MediumQuality = -20
  # Sinr Variables
ExcellentSINR = 20
GoodSINR = 13
MediumSINR = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if (df['Serving Cell RSRP'] >= ExcellentPower) and (df['Serving Cell RSRQ'] >= ExcellentQuality) and (df['RS SINR Carrier 1'] >= ExcellentSINR):
    df = df['Cell State':'Excellent']

    elif (df['Serving Cell RSRP'] >= GoodPower) and   (df['Serving Cell RSRP'] < ExcellentPower) and (df['Serving Cell RSRQ'] >= GoodQuality) and (df['Serving Cell RSRQ'] < ExcellentQuality) and   (df['RS SINR Carrier 1'] >= GoodSINR) and   (df['RS SINR Carrier 1'] < ExcellentSINR)]:
      df = df['Cell State':'Good']

      elif df[(df['Serving Cell RSRP'] >= MediumPower) and   (df['Serving Cell RSRP'] < GoodPower) and (df['Serving Cell RSRQ'] >= MediumQuality) and   (df['Serving Cell RSRQ'] < GoodQuality) and   (df['RS SINR Carrier 1'] >= MediumSINR) and   (df['RS SINR Carrier 1'] < GoodSINR)]:
        df = df['Cell State':'Medium']
        
        elif df(df['Serving Cell RSRP'] < MediumPower) and (df['Serving Cell RSRQ'] < MediumQuality) and (df['RS SINR Carrier 1'] < MediumSINR)):
          df = df['Cell State':'Weak']
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You are iterating through the rows of a DF using `for index, row in df.iterrows():` but then don't use index and row variables but instead do vetorized operations on each iteration.  And you should know that `df['Cell State':'Good']` is not a column slice but is a row slice.  Maybe try `apply(axis=1)` or nested `np.where`.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.